# Pull voice memos into app like image picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Does anyone know if there is a way to access voice memos and get their path sort of the way you can with the image picker to get images and videos.

I am trying to access the voice memos and pick one to upload to the server.

Does anyone know if its possible to access those? I have been searching for a answer to this for a while now and I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access already made voice memos from your app. Your best option is to use `AVAudioRecorder` and let the user record their own memos in your app to upload to the server.

Comment: Thanks that was kind of what I was thinking. I already have it so they can record audio from inside the app. Thanks